# How to get details from AutoCAD DXF file to java application?

Tags: java, api, autocad, dxf

I'm developing application which needs to get details from AutoCAD DXF file. Is there any specific API which support this task. Actually in my project I need to get building structures to my java application and I need to add some more details to those graphs So can some one provide your experience about this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick Google search on [`java dxf`](http://www.google.com/search?q=java+dxf) yields the [ycad](http://ycad.sourceforge.net/) library. I have never used it, I don't know how well it works.

Answer (score 0):

http://caff.de/dxfviewer/ supports reading DXF files.

Answer (score 0):

The reading of an AutoCAD DXF file is not a trivial task. The contained entities can be affected by the coordinate systems, the blocks can be hierarchycal, etc. When I wrote my DXF importer, I read the file sequentialy, built a DXF DOM and then converted it into my own format. You can find the document specification here:

http://images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/autocad_2012_pdf_dxf-reference_enu.pdf

http://www.autodesk.com/techpubs/autocad/acadr14/dxf/dxf_reference.htm